# Что должна возвращать функция printf() в случае ошибки?

Tags: c

Читаю ман по printf(): "В случае успеха, возвращается количество напечатанных байт. В случае ошибки возвращается отрицательное значение.".

Ок, хорошо. Есть такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main( int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[] ){
    
    int res;
    
    close( 1 );
    
    res = printf( "0_0\n" );
    perror( "printf" );
    dprintf( 2, "code is %i\n", res );
    
    return 0;
}
```

В коде я закрываю stdout и вызываю printf(), которая должна вернуть -1... ну в теории.
Запускаем и видим:

```
$ ./main 
printf: Bad file descriptor
code is 4
```

Это как так-то? Функция явно завершилась с ошибкой, но вернула при этом число байт.

Система линукс, компилятор gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` заимствует часть требований от `fprintf`, в т.ч. чтобы `stdout` указывал на файловый поток. Ломая `stdout` (причем именно ломая, так как закрывается он посредством `fclose`, а закрытие нижележащего файлового дескриптора переводит поток в неконсистентное состояние), вы нарушаете требования к входящим параметрам для вызова `printf` и получаете Неопределенное Поведение.

Как продолжение, было бы интересно узнать, когда же `printf` может все-таки возвратить ошибку при корректном вызове? По идее, такой сценарий можно устроить, если например запустить этот процесс как дочерний, передав ему в качестве дескриптора `stdout` вход от `pipe`, и затем закрыв выход в родительском процессе.

Comment: Теперь понял, спасибо. Заменил close() на fclose() и возвращаемое значение стало -1. Я до этого почему-то думал, что вызовы close() и fclose() эквивалентны и закрывают файловый поток. Теперь понял свою ошибку.

Comment: @64-coreCPU Закрывая `stdout` вы по-прежнему получаете Неопределенное Поведение. Только теперь все стало еще хуже, так как `stdout` перестает быть валидным указателем.

Comment: Где прочитать про требования для функций? В манах указано, что функция выводит текст на stdout, но про требования я там ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Требования можно почитать в стандарте  ISO C. `stdout` должен быть валидным, указатель на строку формата должен указывать на строку с валидным форматом, прочие аргументы должны соответствовать строке формата.

Comment: Получается, если вызывающий процесс закроет stdout и вызовет мою программу с помощью execve, то жди беды? Что ж, это неплохая тема для подумать...

Comment: @64-coreCPU Нет, речь шла о закрытии читающего конца pipe, который не передается в дочерний процесс, туда передается пишущий конец pipe, который остается открытым и валидным, но только записать в него будет нельзя.

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду вот так https://paste.ee/p/Ai6Se

Comment: Получается, что вызывающий процесс закрывает дескриптор и на вход printf подаётся невалидный stdout.

Comment: Ваш пример не имеет ничего общего с тем, что я описал. Хотя бы потому, что там нигде не создается пайпов, чтобы иметь возможность закрыть читающий конец.

Comment: Я пытаюсь рассмотреть именно ту ситуацию, когда stdout закрыт. Первоначально именно с этим вопросом я сюда пришёл. С пайпами у меня вопросов нет - если начать писать в пайп/сокет, который закрыт с той стороны, то прилетит sigpipe.